# How to evaluate $\int_0^4xe^{(x-2)^4}dx=K$ such that $K=\text{constant}$?

Tags: integration, functions, derivatives

I am having trouble with an integration problem:

$$\int_0^4xe^{(x-2)^4}dx=K, \space \space K=\text{constant}.$$

If anyone could point me to the right theory or provide tips on how solve it would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

[Click her for the to see the Integral.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ynskP.jpg)

Comment: Wolframalpha gives this: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%5Cint_0%5E4+x*e%5E%28%28x-2%29%5E4%29+dx

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It is in your best interest that you type your questions (using [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)) instead of posting links to pictures.

Comment: @Peter13 why do you think this integral can be calculated ?

Comment: What is the **background** of the problem?  
If the problem is from a contest, which contest?  
If (instead) the problem is from a book &/or class, 
what theorems or previously (solved) problems has your 
book or class focused on that you think might be pertinent here?

Comment: I (unsuccessfully) tried **meta-cheating**, and assumed that the problem can be manually (i.e. no computer software) solved in a straightforward manner.  My first *try* was $u = (x-2)$, which transformed the integrand into $(u+2)e^{u^4}.$  In searching for an **antiderivative** I surmised that this *improvement* is illusory, because the resulting integrand (still) doesn't lend itself to integration by parts. ...see next comment

Comment: Continuing with the meta-cheating, but abandoning the the search for an antiderivative, this leaves capitalizing on the fact that the problem involves a definite rather than indefinite integral.  This is the stopping point of my abilities.  My (**vague**) consequential ideas are either to look for symmetry in the bounds of integration, or consider using a taylor series.